# Combinatorics Question- how many different marble bags can you get...?

Tags: combinatorics

The question is "You want to buy a bag of 13 marbles, and there are 4 different marble colors (red, blue, green, yellow) to choose from. Any two marbles of the same color are indistinguishable. Buying 10 red and 3 blue marbles gives the same bag as buying 3 blue and 10 red marbles. Also, a bag consisting of 13 green marbles (and no other colors) is certainly possible. How many different bags could you buy?"
My initial thought, since the marble colors are indistinguishable, would be 13! different bags but also thought of the possibility of 13 choose 4, since we have 4 different marble colors. Can someone explain? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like we are interested in [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_partitions) of $13$ into up to $4$ parts.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - but it sounds like $13$ red is not the same as $13$ green, so wouldn't this be [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))?

Comment: @antkam The problem explicitly states that marble colors are indistinguishable.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - in that case you are of course correct, but i wonder if that is because the OP mis-spoke.  the quoted part of the question does not say colors are indistinguishable but rather marbles of the same color are indistinguishable.  maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: The marble colors are all indistinguishable I believe

Comment: if "$13$ reds" is the same as "$13$ greens", i.e. they don't count as "different" bags, then you're counting partitions.  if they count as "different", then use stars and bars.